# How to disable fullReset

Tags: appium

How to disable fullReset?

Here is my code

```html
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities(); // экземпляр класса настроек
cap.SetCapability("deviceName", "Redmi4X"); // имя девайся (абсолютно любое)
cap.SetCapability("platformVersion", "6.0.1");// версия платформы (тоже любая)
cap.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");//имя платформы
cap.SetCapability("appPackage", "com.facebook.katana"); // пространство имен используемое приложением
cap.SetCapability("appActivity", ".LoginActivity"); // активное окно
 
AndroidDriver<IWebElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap); // инициализируем экземпляр класса драйвера с настроечками
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300)); //экземпляр класса для ожидания
```

Answer (score 1):

With the following capabilities you can disable Full reset etc.

**If you want to start the app with all the previous data. Then use the following flags.**

```
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET, false);
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, true);
```

**If you want to clear the cache and settings, but leave the app installed before each start then use the following capabilities**

```
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET, false);
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, false);
```